# How to check if filefield is in use

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class AdClientForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label=u'text', required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=AdmImageWidget(), label=u'Image', required=False)

    def clean(self):
        ???
```

And how to check if a field image was used? This means the user has selected a file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AdClientForm, self).clean()
    if not cleaned_data['image']:
         raise forms.ValidationError("No image")
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Always I get None, regardless of the state.